# Azure 4 min timeout in web app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, bigdata, iis-8

My project is an ASP.NET MVC 4 project.

While in localhost it works fine when I host it in Azure
I get a timeout in ajax calls that take more than 4 minutes.
I am sure that the  problem is with azure because it doesn't matter what I'm doing in the server.
even just set `Thread.sleep(300000)` I get a timeout.

I read in:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-configurable-idle-timeout-for-azure-load-balancer/
That

> a common practice to keep the connection active for a longer period is
>   to use TCP Keep-alive

and there is no other option for web apps.
So I guess that what I need is help to keep alive code in asp.net.
I can't figure this out by myself. 
 tried to send every one minute simple ajax call to the server and this doesn't help me
so I tried to use TcpKeepAlive like this:

```
public JsonResult MyLongOperation()
{
    HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("mySite");
    request.Proxy = null;
    request.ServicePoint.SetTcpKeepAlive(true, 30000, 5000); 
    Thread.Sleep(300000);//5 min sleep
    return  Json("ok",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Didn't work,i need help please!!

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem too, found this, worked for me:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-configurable-idle-timeout-for-azure-load-balancer/

Comment: this is the link i put in my question.
as you can see i even quoted 
" common practice to keep the connection active for a longer period is to use TCP Keep-alive"
that because Idle time out is not supported for Azure Webapps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried request.KeepAlive=true; ?