# Timeout after 4 minute long server call in azure webapp

Tags: azure, timeout

I have a webapp in Azure where i upload various excel files and then there is data processing on the uploaded files, the screen throws a 500 error after 4 minutes.

Tried every thing but just can't get it worked.
Please suggest a quick and easy fix

Note: I have tried **Always On** feature also but no luck

Regards

Comment: If there is a 500 coming back, do you get a response error message too?  Easiest way to see those would be in the browser's F12 tools on the network tab.  That would be helpful to help troubleshoot what your problem may be on the server.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449600/azure-4-min-timeout-in-web-app

Comment: @Mani had look but it is not clearly explained

Comment: @JasonHaleyconsole tab has following error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()" and the Network tab has following error "500 - The request timed out. The web server failed to respond within the specified time."

Answer (score 0):

You could use a webjob for your long running operations. You would not get any timout error anymore.

Comment: Can you brief on that, how to do that using a webjob

Comment: A webjob can help you to decouple your long running operations from your website. In your case, you could use one as a background task to execute operations on the excels files. If you upload your excels files in a blob storage, the web job could start when a new blob is uploaded in the storage, this [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-webjobs-readme/) can help you.